# pytorch NaNLabelEncoder to encode and decode categorical target

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm new to pytorch but it feels like this should be simple. How do I inverse transform this tensor?

```
classification_dataset = TimeSeriesDataSet(
    df,
    group_ids=['group'],
    target="target_col",  # categorical target
    time_idx="time_idx",
    min_encoder_length= 60 * 60, # how much history to use
    max_encoder_length= 60 * 60,
    min_prediction_length=5,
    max_prediction_length=5,  # how far to predict into future
    time_varying_unknown_reals=[
        
        #...list of columns here
    ],
    #time_varying_unknown_reals=[time_varying_unknown_reals[0]],
    target_normalizer=NaNLabelEncoder(),  # Use the NaNLabelEncoder to encode categorical target
)

x, y = next(iter(classification_dataset.to_dataloader(batch_size=4)))
y[0]  # target values are encoded categories
```

output

```
tensor([[6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

classification_dataset.target_normalizer returns NaNLabelEncoder() but it's not fitted.

Answer (score 0):

ah it's as simple as

```
classification_dataset.target_normalizer.classes_
```